# Where are the ROS Hydro stacks installed?

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can anyone tell me what happened to the (usual) source code location inside the /stacks folder? After an installation of ros-hydro-desktop-full, the size of /opt/ros/hydro is 279.5 MB compared to Fuerte's 3.1 GB.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75808/where-are-the-ros-hydro-stacks-installed?/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-08-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For packages which have transitioned to the new buildsystem catkin, the source is not installed by default.

If you want the source for a debian package.  Duplicate the packages.ros.org line in your apt.sources.list file and put 'deb-src' instead of 'deb'

Then you can `apt-get source PACKAGENAME`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3